# How to create a tag system on my Access database?

Tags: database-design, ms-access, listagg

I work with Access in a very rudimentary way. I use it to store data about events that involves guests and our staff. The amount of people in total is enormous, so it is imposible to add the people in one table and then selected in the other. I need to creat a tag like way to add several guests in the one cell to it in the activities table and that to be interpreted into different elements in the guests table. Just like a tag sistem, where you can have several tags for element and vice versa. It have been impossible to me to have more than one value in the same cell, except for using a selection tool with a preexisting table. How can I do that? It is possible at all in Microsoft Access?

Comment: Cool, cool, cool. So what's the question?